# Any subset of Baire space is a union of a boldface $\Delta_2^0$ set and a set with no isolated points.  Anybody know how to prove this?

Tags: lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I'm trying to do due diligence and determine whether this is known, trivial, original, etc.  I have a proof of:

Theorem: If $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ then $S=X\cup Y$ for some $X$ which is boldface $\mathbf{\Delta}_2^0$ and some $Y$ with no isolated points, with $X\cap Y=\emptyset$.

Anybody else have a proof of this?

Comment: The usual Cantor-Bendixson theorem tells you that your set $S$ is the disjoint union of a countable set $X$ and a set $Y$ with no isolated points.  The countable set is boldface $\Sigma^0_2$.  
But the countable set is scattered, i.e., every subset has an isolated point.  Does this somehow give you boldface $\Pi^0_2$ as well?
Or do you use a different decomposition?

Comment: Stefan, isn't every countable set boldface $\Delta^0_1$? (or better?) This would make the result an immediate consequence of the Cantor-Bendixon argument. Just throw out isolated points until there are none left, in a transfinite recursion; one obtains the original set as a union of a countable set (hence $\Delta^0_2$) and a set with no isoltated points, as desired.

Comment: Ahh, that is right.  Thanks Joel.  I failed to realize the Cantor-Bendixson rank is always countable, but now that I think about it, of course it is.

In light of all this, here is an interesting alternate statement of CBT:  "Every $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a disjoint union of a countable set $X$ and a set with no isolated points $Y$; and $Y$ can be taken to be closed if $S$ is closed (in which case the union is unique)"

Comment: @Joel: Boldface `$\Delta^0_1$` is the same as clopen, so nonempty countable sets are not `$\Delta^0_1$`.  They are `$\Sigma^0_2$` (i.e., `$F_\sigma$`), as Stefan said, but an additional argument is needed to get `$\Pi^0_2$` (i.e., `$G_\delta$`).  That argument will need something like scatteredness, since a countable dense set can't be `$G_\delta$` by the Baire category theorem.

Comment: Yes, I've come to the same conclusion myself. My comment above is not correct.

Comment: Further searching online has revealed the following.  Scattered implies $G_{\delta}$ (i.e., $\Pi_2^0$) but this is nontrivial.  A lot of references are given by Dave Renfro in this sci.math thread:
http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/math/56911/Scattered-sets-are-G-delta


Answer (score 1):

Stefan Geschke and Joel David Hamkins pointed out that this is a corollary of the proof of the Cantor-Bendixson theorem.  In fact, we can strengthen the conclusion:  X is not just $\Delta_2^0$, it is countable and scattered(*).  And the proof, like that of Cantor-Bendixson's theorem, is simple:  remove isolated points repeatedly until none remain (this may take more than $\omega$ steps and require ordinals, but a simple argument shows it only requires ordinals below $\omega_1$, and thus only countably many isolated points need to be removed).

(*Scattered implies $G_{\delta}$, though this is not trivial.  Thus countable+scattered is strictly stronger than $\Delta_2^0$)